Is there a way to install Redisearch on EC2 Instance?
I have installed my Redis on my EC2 instance, now my goal is to create a RAG using this Redis instance. But when I try my "ft.create" command, it says
unknown command 'FT.CREATE', with args beginning with

So this means, my EC2 is not having redisearch. Is there a way to get it so I can get my RAG on my EC2 instance?

I recommend using Redis Stack, which integrates Redis with the additional modules for search, JSON, probabilistic data structures, and time series.
Note also that Redis 8 M01 is available for testing. From Redis 8 on, the standard Redis Community Edition will integrate search (including full-text, vector, numeric, geo, and exact match) and the rest of the capabilities.
